# Please suggest that how to convert canvas into bit64?

Tags: jquery, canvas

I am recently started working on canvas , but i am stuck here I have to convert canvas into base64 without using canvas2html? How to do that

Comment: use canvas.toDataURL() method

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```